# Returning multiple separated errors in Dropzone for error() event

Tags: javascript, json, file-upload, upload, dropzone.js

When the server returns an error HTTP code (i.e. non-200) then Dropzone triggers the `error(file, responseText)` event with the JSON that you pass back. This works fine if `parallelUploads` is 1, but how do we handle the case for `parallelUploads` > 1?

In this case each POST sends 2+ files, but if only some of them have an error, how do we format the return JSON so Dropzone doesn't fire an error event for *all* the files in the request?